# Validate loading CSS with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, validation, xhtml

I have two style sheets, one default style and one Christmas style. I would like the Christmas style to be loaded in December and the default to be used in every other month.

I have written the code below which achieves what I want, however if I put it in to a validator I get the error: "document type does not allow element "link" here". I was wondering how I could make this code validate?

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = new Date();
        var m = i.getMonth();
        if (m==11) {
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle-christmas.css" />');
        } else {
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle-default.css" />');
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: do you want to do this with javascript only? I mean you could do it with any code behind such as C# vb.net or Php

Answer (score 3):

The validator has problems because you're not using CDATA, thus the validator will parse your javascript. Use the following to solve your problem:

```
<head>
    <script>
    //<![CDATA[
        // Your code here
    // ]]>
    </script>
</head>
```

Btw, the following is a better way to do it:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = new Date(),
            m = i.getMonth(),
            l = document.createElement( 'link' )

        l.rel = 'stylesheet'

        if ( m === 11 ) {
            l.href = 'mystyle-christmas.css'
        }
        else {
            l.href = 'mystyle-default.css'
        }

        document.getElementsByTagName( 'HEAD' )[ 0 ].appendChild( l )
    </script>
</head>
```

And an even better way is to have your javascript in an external js file.

Comment: I agree that having an external js file would be best and that is what I had tried to do once I had the code working locally but couldn't get it to work for some reason. Any suggestions as to how I could use my code in an external file?

Comment: Put it in a js file and don't add the script tags in the js file.

Comment: I put my existing code in a js file as is but I couldn't get it to be called in the html .. sorry, I know I'm being dumb, I've not used JavaScript before!

Comment: Don't forget to add `<script src="path/to/file.js"></script>` in your html file.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the element instead of using `document.write`:

```
  var christmas = document.createElement("link");
  christmas.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  christmas.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
  christmas.setAttribute("href", "mystyle-christmas.css");

  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(christmas)
```